# Incorrect Server Response in Ckeditor Django

Tags: django, ckeditor

I want a non-admin user to be able to send an image on ckeditor's post.

The problem happens that I can send the image in the post if the user is admin but if it is a simple user I cannot because it shows Incorrect Server Response in Ckeditor Django.

my settings below:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


SECRET_KEY = 'l$+3%scpx$n(ne!ky6b#!1p6q7pw-cnvl2*35v9_4akia0hswn'

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['devcapivara.com.br', 'www.devcapivara.com.br']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #My Apps
    'accounts',
    'core',
    'post',

    #third 
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'easy_thumbnails',
]

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/' 

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'capivara_blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'capivara_blog.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# auth
LOGIN_URL = 'accounts:login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'core:dashboard'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'accounts:login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'accounts:logout'

# Usando o módulo USER da nossa aplicação ACCOUNTS
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

# Autenticação por email/username
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'accounts.backends.ModelBackend',
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Fortaleza'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ( "DD-MM-AAAA", )


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/html/capivara_blog/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/html/capivara_blog/media/'
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644


CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {'default':
                        {'toolbar': 'Custom', 'height': 600,'width':1000,'toolbar_Custom':
                            [
                                ['Format', 'Bold', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Image'],
                                ['CodeSnippet'],
                            ],'extraPlugins': 'codesnippet',
                         }}


#SETTINGS LOCAL
try:
    exec(open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'capivara_blog/settings_local.py')).read())
except IOError as e:
    pass
```

what can I do to allow simple users to send images in the post?

Answer (score 2):

It's because by default, ckeditor has @super-user decoration in its urls. Try:

In your mysite-> urls.py add the following to replace @super-user decoration with @login_required decoration

```
from ckeditor_uploader import views as ckeditor_views

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

url(r'^ckeditor/upload/', login_required(ckeditor_views.upload), name='ckeditor_upload'),
url(r'^ckeditor/browse/', never_cache(login_required(ckeditor_views.browse)), name='ckeditor_browse'),
```

Hope it helps.